# cakePHP, form helper, creating a form automatically - how?

Tags: cakephp, form-helpers

Is there a way to get form helper to create the inputs of the form (retrieved from db table) by itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The fastest way to create a form](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/06/09/15-essential-cakephp-tips/):

```
echo $form->create();
echo $form->inputs();
echo $form->end();
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the code cake uses for scaffold, its basically doing a foreach on $Model->schema() and echoing an input for each field. Cake will already pick an input type for the field so the rest is automatic